# Get delta from two XmlSerializer outputs

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm writing an audit log that saves the delta between two serialized objects of the same type. Is there a way to easily prune out nodes that have the same value and leave the ones that changed?

```
StreamWriter oldData = new StreamWriter();
StreamWriter newData = new StreamWriter();
XmlSerializer xmlOld = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
XmlSerializer xmlNew = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));

xmlOld.Serialize(oldData, obj);
xmlNew.Serialize(newData, obj);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft provides a tool 'XMLDiffPatch' that is pretty easy to use, and will provide the output that you are looking for.  Here is a handy little guide for it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx

Basically you will use the tool to identify what you should drop out from your two items and then go from there.

Comment: This isn't bad, however I'd like to avoid external tools.

Comment: Yes of course, but the alternative is doing the diff yourself, which is time consuming and filled with edge cases.